# Convert dict with lists in values to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary with the following keys and values

```
my_dict={'1':{'name':'one',
              'f_10':[1,10,20,30],
              'f_20':[1,20,40,60]},
        '2':{'name':'two',
              'f_10':[2,12,22,32],
              'f_20':[2,22,42,62]}}
```

How do I convert it to a Pandas `DataFrame` that will look like:

```
name      name      f_10           f_20
1         one       [1,10,20,30]   [1,10,20,60]
2         two       [2,12,22,32]   [2,22,42,62]
```

The lists need to be considered in one column based on the key, if I try to `concat` these get converted to separate rows in the data frame.

Comment: what have you tried so far to try and convert your nested Dict into a df?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would parse that dictionary to DataFrame and have it transposed. For example,

```
pd.DataFrame(my_dict).T
```

Result

```
    name  f_10              f_20
1   one   [1, 10, 20, 30]   [1, 20, 40, 60]
2   two   [2, 12, 22, 32]   [2, 22, 42, 62]
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `orient=index` when importing your data using `from_dict`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient = 'index')
```

This returns:

```
    name    f_10    f_20
1   one     [1, 10, 20, 30]     [1, 20, 40, 60]
2   two     [2, 12, 22, 32]     [2, 22, 42, 62]
```